# get max, min, count and mode (occurrence)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an items table in my database that i want my query to process the values and give me the data of the max price, min price, most recurrent max price in that specific item category and no of items (and ignore the ones that are null), so here is my items table:

| id | category | min_price | max_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | kids | 10 | 100 |
| 2 | adult | 20 | 200 |
| 3 | both | null | null |
| 4 | adult | 20 | 100 |
| 5 | adult | 50 | 100 |
| 6 | adult | 50 | 200 |
| 7 | kids | 20 | 100 |
| 8 | both | 20 | 100 |
| 9 | kids | null | null |
| 10 | adult | 10 | 500 |
| 11 | misc | null | null |

I want the query to return this result:

| category | min_price | max_price | price_mode | no_items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| kids | 10 | 100 | 100 | 3 |
| adult | 20 | 500 | 200 | 5 |
| both | 20 | 100 | 100 | 2 |
| misc | null | null | null | 1 |

so just to further explain the adult lowest price in 20 and highest is 500 and the 100 and 200 max_price has 2 occurrences both i want to take the highest as the price_mode which is 200 in this case and the no_items is just the count of how many times adult is shown in the table.

am struggling to get the mode honestly and grouping it correctly to get the output I want.

Below is the commands to create table and feed it with data. Tried to put it in SqlFiddle but that's not working for me i don't know why.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `min_price` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_price` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  );
INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `category`, `min_price`, `max_price`) VALUES
  ('kids', 10, 100),
  ('adult', 20, 200),
  ('both', null, null),
  ('adult', 20, 100),
  ('adult', 50, 100),
  ('adult', 50, 200),
  ('kids', 20, 100),
  ('both', 20, 100),
  ('kids', null, null),
  ('adult', 10, 500),
  ('misc', null, null);
```

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Custom MODE() function usable like MIN() or AVG() in MySQL](//stackoverflow.com/q/21929924/90527)", "[How do I get the median/mode/range of a column in SQL using Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2616168/90527)", "[Calculating Mode within existing query to count rows in PHP and MySQL](//stackoverflow.com/q/13048972/90527)"

Comment: Hi @outis, thank you very much for your time, I already saw these posts in the past few days and unfortunately, I still failed to build the query. I add the code for creating the table and feeding it to the question hoping this will help to get my question answered.

Comment: If by "Tried to put it in SqlFiddle but that's not working", you're referring to an "Oops! Something went wrong." error (and long delay) on SQLFiddle when building schema, it's because the backing SQL servers sometimes go down. I sent a message to the company that runs the site a few days ago, but haven't heard back.

Comment: Please expand the problem description to demonstrate why it's not a duplicate of the other questions (and to narrow down on the specific issue you're having), and also include your best-effort at writing a query.

Comment: Seems like `adult` lowest price is `10` based on the sample data. See `id=10`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your create table + insert data syntax doesn't work in fiddle because your data `VALUES` are for just 3 columns whereby you define 4 columns in the `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `category`, `min_price`, `max_price`) VALUES
                             ('kids' ,     10     ,      100),
             /*where's the value for `id`?*/
...
```

If you remove `id` from the `INSERT` syntax, it won't work as well because you've set it as `PRIMARY KEY` so it can't be empty. What you can do in addition to removing `id` from `INSERT` is to define `AUTO_INCREMENT` on the `id` column:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
....
```

Now, to get the expected result on your `price_mode`, you may want to try using `GROUP_CONCAT()` with `ORDER` and define which of the data in there that you want to return. Let's say you do `GROUP_CONCAT(max_price ORDER BY max_price DESC)` to return the set with `max_price` in descending order like this:

```
SELECT category,
       MIN(min_price),
       MAX(max_price),
       GROUP_CONCAT(max_price ORDER BY max_price DESC),
       COUNT(*)
FROM items
GROUP BY category;
```

Then you'll get a result like this:

| category | MIN(min_price) | MAX(max_price) | GROUP_CONCAT(max_price ORDER BY max_price DESC) | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| adult | 10 | 500 | 500,200,200,100,100 | 5 |
| both | 20 | 100 | 100 | 2 |
| kids | 10 | 100 | 100,100 | 3 |
| misc | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 |

So, there's a consistent pattern in the `GROUP_CONCAT()` result that you probably can work out with. Assuming that you want the second largest value in the set, you can apply `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` twice to get it like this:

```
SELECT category,
       MIN(min_price) AS min_price,
       MAX(max_price) AS max_price,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                 GROUP_CONCAT(max_price ORDER BY max_price DESC),',',2),',',-1)
               AS price_mode,
       COUNT(*) AS no_items
FROM items
GROUP BY category;
```

This return the following result:

| category | min_price | max_price | price_mode | no_items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| adult | 10 | 500 | 200 | 5 |
| both | 20 | 100 | 100 | 2 |
| kids | 10 | 100 | 100 | 3 |
| misc | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 |

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=736442cfac3c73b3c2bcb53a192c36b2)

The following is an updated suggestion after getting further clarification:

```
SELECT i.category,
       MIN(i.min_price),
       MAX(i.max_price),
       v2.mp AS price_mode,
       COUNT(DISTINCT i.id)
  FROM items i
  LEFT JOIN
(SELECT cat,
       mp,
       cnt,
       CASE WHEN cat = @cat 
              THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
              ELSE @rownum:=1 END AS rownum, 
               @cat := cat
FROM
(SELECT category cat,
        max_price mp,
        COUNT(*) cnt
FROM items
GROUP BY category,
        max_price) v1
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 1,
                         @cat := NULL) seq
WHERE mp IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY cat, cnt DESC, mp DESC) v2
ON i.category=v2.cat
 AND v2.rownum=1
GROUP BY i.category, v2.mp;
```

The query starts with getting the `COUNT(*)` value of `category` and `max_price` combination. Then generating a custom row numbering on it with a `WHERE` condition that doesn't return `max_price` with `NULL` after the first operation. Probably the crucial part here is the `ORDER BY cat, cnt DESC, mp DESC` since the row numberings are assigned based on it. Otherwise, the row numbering will mess up. Finally, `LEFT JOIN` the `items` table with it with `ON i.category=v2.cat AND v2.rownum=1` condition. It's important to make sure the `v2.rownum=1` is placed at `ON` condition instead of `WHERE` in order to return the last row value of `misc`; since the subqueries will not have the value with the present sample data.

[Here's an updated fiddle for reference](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=db349626bb1c6ec145786179ac7547a4), including the sample of 3 `adult=NULL`.

Comment: I suddenly have a realization on how `price_mode` is obtained.

Comment: Thanks, @FanoFN for explaining the answer in this great way, I really learned a lot!, I think the query you provided gets the 2nd entry in the GROUP_CONCAT column so if we imagine the first row is 500,500,200,200,200,100,100,100 it will give 500 where is should be giving 200 as it is the highest mode. do you think its doable by MySQL or should i just receive it as a string then just get the max mode in code?

Comment: Yes.. that was what I thought you were aiming for but after reading your question and looking at the other answer, I realize it's not the case. I'll think it will need a subquery but I haven't figured out how yet.. Once I have it, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts in helping me out @FanoFN

Comment: @MustafaAl-Ani , looks like you'll need a bunch of subqueries : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1f8cf5446b380ee1a55bd02c8ba36333 . This is largely assuming that you're using older MySQL version though, you can check version by running `SELECT version();` . If you're on MySQL v8+ (or MariaDB v10.2) and above, I can suggest you a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, am working on MySQL 5.7 and your solution is working great in the fiddle, but when i implemented it on the mass data that i have there is a scenario where it is failing which is, for example, if we have 3 adult entries with 'null' then the price mode comes as null, i tried adding where max_price is not null but that removes the entry of misc as it has only null values and i need to get the null if there is no prices listed to that category, can you plz guide me to where to put my condition to exclude the null only when i have not null prices for that category

Comment: I think you can use `IFNULL` to replace null values with zeros. It should be correct to assume that `NULL=0`, right?

Comment: Let me try an alternative method and get back to you.

Comment: no in my case it's not null=0, so if null is within numbers then is should be ignored but if there is only null to that category then null should be the output (as in misc currently)

Comment: I see. Have you tried my updated solution yet? Is it still not working?

Comment: Wow! works great!! thanks alot for your efforts! i think i got lots of studying to do to understand the query you provided :D ... I really appreciate it :) ... I hope someday i can write similar queries

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this query will help

```
with maximumvaluecounts
as ( select 
     count(max_price) as c, category, max_price 
     from yourtable
     group by category 
),
maximumcountpercategory
as ( select category,max(c) as c 
     from maximumvaluecounts 
     group by category
),
modes as ( select category, max_price as modevalue 
           from maximumcountpercategory m1
           join maximumvaluecounts m2
              on m1.category=m2.category
               and m1.c=m2.c
          )
, others as (
select 
category,
min(min_price) as min_price,
max(max_price) as max_price,
count(max_price) as no_items
from yourtable 
group by category 
)
select o.*, m.modevalue as price_mode
from others o join 
modes m on o.category=m.category
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i ran the query but it says this error -> RROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'maximumvaluecounts
as ( select 
     count(max_price) as c, category, max_price ' at line 1 .

Sorry am a new dev and not a real pro in MySQL so couldn't figure out the error, can you help plz